# How to apply search filter on serialized data in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I am having following Serialized data in my DB table.

I want to perform a search of "Key Name": "%value%". I am having serialized data in the following format.

## **My serialized Data**

```
a:31:{s:10:"contact_no";s:11:"1234-123456";s:13:"guardian_name";s:11:"Atif, Ashif";s:7:"program";s:10:"Essex SCHS";s:15:"sub_coordinator";s:3:"abc";s:7:"daycare";s:3:"abc";s:18:"daycare_contact_no";s:10:"9013256590";s:14:"daycare_tel_no";s:11:"1234-123456";s:9:"specialty";s:3:"abc";s:7:"address";s:3:"abc";s:4:"city";s:3:"abc";s:5:"state";s:2:"MT";s:8:"zip_code";s:6:"123456";s:8:"phone_no";s:10:"9033153594";s:8:"extra_no";s:10:"1234567890";s:9:"mobile_no";s:10:"9033153594";s:13:"contact_notes";s:3:"abc";s:8:"email_id";s:15:"abc@example.com";s:6:"fax_no";s:10:"1234567890";s:9:"id_number";s:3:"123";s:16:"service_provided";s:3:"abc";s:12:"case_manager";s:3:"308";s:18:"additonal_language";s:3:"abc";s:3:"sex";s:4:"male";s:10:"birth_date";s:10:"01/24/2018";s:17:"initial_isfp_date";s:10:"12/27/2017";s:13:"isfp_received";s:10:"12/12/2017";s:9:"isfp_date";s:10:"12/27/2017";s:11:"assign_date";s:10:"12/27/2017";s:10:"fvc_due_by";s:10:"12/19/2017";s:14:"email_approval";s:2:"no";s:9:"id_status";s:6:"active";}
```

I have tried the following query for this but I don't succeed.

## **Query I have tried**,

```
SELECT * FROM ta_children c
JOIN ta_children_meta cm ON c.id = cm.child_id 
WHERE cm.child_data like '%atif%' AND cm.child_data like '%guardian_name%'
```

in query **guardian_name** is key and **%atif%** search value. Here this is single but it may be dynamic. So, please answer for dynamic search for this.

**Required:** How to achieve the search for my serialized data with the key-value pair.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That's why you should normalize your database.

Comment: ok, but for this situation. Do you've any solution?

Comment: No, to get a solid solution you would need to parse the serialized data and mysql cannot unserialize a string that has been generated by php's `serialize()`.

Comment: that will increase the page speed, due to serialize and filter for each record.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `REGEXP`  regular expression for this :

```
SELECT * FROM ta_children c
JOIN ta_children_meta cm ON c.id = cm.child_id 
WHERE cm.child_data  REGEXP '.*"array_key";s:[0-9]+:".*array_value.*".*'
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. But it's not giving the proper result.